# Streamlit Share cloud can not find package / module

Tags: python, module, package, streamlit

I have transfered a locally running Streamlit file to the **Streamlite-Share cloud**. This Share-cloud envirnoment tells me, that the Python packeage **pandas_datareader** can not be found. Any idea what is to do now ? Thank you!

```py
import streamlit as st
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/streamlit_finance_data/str04.py", line 5, in <module>
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Streamlit cloud you need to specify in your project the dependencies.
This can be done using an added [reuirements.txt](https://realpython.com/lessons/using-requirement-files/) and specifying in it the libraries you want streamlit to install when it deploys your app.

This is elaborated in the [documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/app-dependencies).